# How to setup two jetty instances as separate unix service in the same server

Tags: java, deployment, jetty, web-deployment, jetty-9

How to setup two jetty instances as separate unix services in the same server.

Followed this and was able to setup jetty as a service for one instance and it was working- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#startup-unix-service.

Tried these steps:

- Create two jetty instances in /opt/jetty-app1 and /opt/jetty-app2.
  Download and unzip jetty9 distribution zip files. Create context xml
  files in the webapps folder of jetty-app1 and jetty-app2 to point to
  the war file locations
- Create a file - /etc/init.d/jetty and /etc/init.d/jetty2. Copy the
  contents of bin/shell.sh to both the files
- Create two files /etc/default/jetty and /etc/default/jetty2 with the
  contents  "JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty-app1" and
  "JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty-app2" respectively
- Try running service jetty start and service jetty2 start. First
  command works, but the second command returns the error
  jetty2.service is not found

How to add a second jetty service?

**Edit 1**

/etc/init.d/jetty start
/etc/init.d jetty2 start is working

but sudo service jetty start is working and sudo service jetty2 start is not working

**Resolved**
To run the next jetty process, had to run this command update-rc.d jetty2 defaults

The issue was resolved, but I wanted to know how it was not needed for the first step and not for the second one. Can anyone help me out,what actually happens here. Is the method wrong for starting multiple instances of jetty

Comment: There is rarely a need to have 2 separate Jetty instances running.  You can setup separate named connectors wired to specific webapps and accomplish the same end result with 1 JVM.

Answer (score 0):

To run the next jetty process, had to run this command
update-rc.d jetty2 defaults

Comment: The issue was resolved, but I wanted to know how it was not needed for the first step and not for the second one. Can anyone help me out,what actually happens here

Comment: Ubuntu (some versions) ships with Jetty - so is it possible there was already a jetty instance installled before - so the update-rc.d jetty defaults had effectively been done before, so you just needed to do it for the non-standard second instance??